# "message": "Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to build a rest API with node express and MongoDB, when I try to test my API with postman I getting this response

> "message": "Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined"

bellow I have attached all my server-side code. first, I have config my application with mongo and started developing the models and respective controllers for that model. inside the controller, I have defined my get and post methods. I don't understand why I am getting that response message when I try to send a post request.

### Server Config

```
import Express from "express";
import Mongoose from "mongoose";
import CorsOptions from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import apiRoutes from "./routes/api.js";

const app = Express();

app.use("/api", apiRoutes);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


const CONNECTION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://user:Index-123@cluster0.uhijm.mongodb.net/SustainableIQ?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

Mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL)
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("server running on port: ${PORT}"))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

### Routes

```
import Express from "express";
import {
  getApi,
  createUser,
  adminCreate,
} from "../controller/UserController.js";

const router = Express.Router();

router.get("/", getApi);
router.post("/create", createUser);
router.post("/create-admin", adminCreate);

export default router;
```

### Nodejs Controller

```
import postUser from "../models/postUser.js";
import adminSchema from "../models/adminUser.js";

export const getApi = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    postUser
      .find()
      .exec()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          res.status(200).json(result);
        }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};


export const adminCreate = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const admin = req.body;
    const newAdmin = new adminSchema(admin);

    newAdmin.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    newAdmin.secondName = req.body.secondName;

    await newAdmin.save();
    res.status(201).json(newAdmin);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};

export const createUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = req.body;

    const newPost = new postUser(post);
    newPost.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    newPost.secondName = req.body.secondName;
    newPost.position = req.body.position;
    newPost.compnayName = req.body.compnayName;
    newPost.contactNumber = req.body.contactNumber;
    newPost.email = req.body.email;

    await newPost.save();
    res.status(201).json(newPost);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

### mongodb schema

```
import Mongoose from "mongoose";

var adminSchema = Mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  secondName: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

var adminSchema = Mongoose.model("adminSchema", adminSchema);

export default adminSchema;
```

Comment: Can we see the actual `POST` request you're sending to the API?

Comment: export const adminCreate = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const admin = req.body;
    const newAdmin = new adminSchema(admin);

    newAdmin.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    newAdmin.secondName = req.body.secondName;

    await newAdmin.save();
    res.status(201).json(newAdmin);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};

Comment: Have you tried putting your body parser code before your api routes?